# Can clone object have same scope in singleton pattern?

Tags: php, scope, singleton-methods

In my case, I created a singleton object check below-

```
  class Foo {
     private static $obj = null;
     public static function create_obj () {
          if (self::$obj === null) {
               self::$obj = new self;
          }
         return self::$obj;
    }
  }
```

Then create object check below

```
$obj = Foo::create_obj();
```

Then clone $obj then

```
$obj1 = clone $obj;
```

Then `$obj` and `$obj1` have difference scope why? And how to create only one object if clone then share same scope?

Comment: using clone violates the singleton pattern and I typically make it a private function when I create singletons.

Comment: If it's a singleton, you can simply make everything a static property, so they're all in the same scope.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then $obj and $obj1 have difference scope why?

Because there is absolutely no reason for them to share the same "scope", if by that you mean be the same instance. You implemented that singleton using the method you did, but that have no effect on the rest of the behaviour of PHP. The clone construct does not use your `create_obj()` method, so it will not be a singleton.

> And how to create only one object if clone then share same scope?

By not using clone. If you want your class to be a singleton with this method, you need to always use your singleton creation method.

---

That is hard to tell from just that, but it seems you are having contradictory goals here. If you need two different instances of an object but representing the same instance, **simply use the same instance of the object**. There is virtually no difference.

If you need a single instance of an object to be used throughout a whole script execution, no need for a singleton, simply instantiate it once, then pass it to every other object that needs it. Objects are passed in a reference-like way in PHP, which means that if you pass it to different functions, all functions will be acting on the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this maybe you will find another design pattern which much comfortable for your case. This article helps me a lot

https://github.com/kamranahmedse/design-patterns-for-humans

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.